# Spritekit - Collision approach when touch begins

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, collision

I'm a beginner with Swift and SpriteKit and I am working on a basic game. I have created a Sprite game character (Sapceman) using 2 SKTexture images. When the screen is touched the Sprite image changes from one texture image to another(Jet Pack Fires) and the Sprite is moved around the screen. I want to set up a collision detection (with an Alien Spite) that removes them from the screen but only when the screen is touched and second texture image is displayed and only for the bottom part of the sprite (i.e. when the person touches the screen and the JetPack is fired I want the fire part to "kill" the alien). Appreciate if anyone can offer any suggestions on this

Comment: So basically you want to get notified when fire ball hits the aliens. Right ?

Comment: Well yes, currently the fireball is just part of the Sprite Image (2nd Texture Image). I was thinking I might need to create a new Sprite that displays when Touch Begins and attach it to the existing Sprite and set the collision on this, but not sure if this is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
 static const uint32_t fireBallCategory   = 0x1;     
 static const uint32_t alienCategory  = 0x1 << 1;
```

In adding fire ball and alien method add this,

```
   fireBall.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = fireBallCategory;         
  alien.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = alienCategory;
  fireBall.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = alienCategory;
```

By doing this you will get notified when fireball and aliens meet each other. So after this you have to add logic to hide alien in delegate method. So first set self as contact delegate. Add this line in -(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size method.

```
 self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
```

Implement the contact delegate as follows,

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    SKPhysicsBody *notFireBall;

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask){
    notFireBall = contact.bodyB;
} else {
    notFireBall = contact.bodyA;
}
[notFireBall removeFromParent];      
}
```

Comment: Hi, Yes I have the contact working and the Alien gets removed when contact is made. I think I was trying to make it too complicated by only detecting the collision when a particular image texture was displayed so I've decided to change approach and instead fire a projectile (fireball) from the Spaceman and set the collision here which will achieve what I want. Thanks for the help